# sharepoint ajax call not showing in internet explorer

Tags: javascript, ajax, internet-explorer, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I have a Sharepoint 2013 site set up.  I added a web part to the home page that makes an ajax call to an outside API, and returns JSON data, showing an image and a link.  When you visit the site in Chrome, it works perfectly, however in Internet Explorer (11), it doesn't work.  The odd part is I know that it is running the JS, because it is showing the "No Current News" p tag from the second line.  This is my code:

```
<h1 style="text-align: center">PQA In The News</h1>
<div id="myNewsFeed"><p>No Current News</p></div>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script><script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script><script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
document.getElementById("myNewsFeed").innerHTML = "<p>No Current News</p>";
  var d = new Date();
  var n = d.getTime();
  var mo = 86400000 * 30;
  n = n - mo;
  var queryString = "https://webhose.io/search?token=xxxx&format=json&q=Company%20Name&ts=" + n;
  loadJSON(queryString);

         function loadJSON(newsURI){
            var data_file = newsURI;
            var http_request = new XMLHttpRequest();
            try{
               // Opera 8.0+, Firefox, Chrome, Safari
               http_request = new XMLHttpRequest();
            }catch (e){
               // Internet Explorer Browsers
               try{
                  http_request = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");

               }catch (e) {

                  try{
                     http_request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                  }catch (e){
                     // Something went wrong
                     alert("Your browser broke!");
                     return false;
                  }

               }
            }

            http_request.onreadystatechange = function(){

               if (http_request.readyState == 4  ){
                  var jsonObj = JSON.parse(http_request.responseText);
                 DisplayData(jsonObj);
               }
            }

            http_request.open("GET", data_file, true);
            http_request.send();
         }


function DisplayData(data) {
  var htmlSource = "<ul>";
  for(var i=0; i < data.posts.length; i++) {
    htmlSource += "<li><a href=\"" + data.posts[i].url + "\"><img src=\"" + data.posts[i].thread.main_image + "\" height=\"150px\" width=\"150px\">" + data.posts[i].title + "</a></li>";  
  }
  htmlSource += "</ul>"
  document.getElementById("myNewsFeed").innerHTML = htmlSource;
}

});</script>
```

I changed the Query String, because it has my company's key, but I can assure you it works.  On Chrome, this shows everything fine, but in IE it just shows "No Current News".

Did I do anything wrong, or does Internet Explorer have something against Ajax?

Comment: You can delegate ajax request management to Jquery instead of implementing by yourself, see https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by Kalamarico best way is to use jquery ajax call and also add fail handler to check exact error. In the above code your javascript call is working but it might not be going to ready state 4 and hence not setting the value.  Can you check for other states and also should not be the http request call inside readystatechange event inside else otherwise after hitting ready state 4 also it will fire again.